# Running debug on older Android 4.4.2 using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, gradle

I am trying to debug on an older Android device (Samsung Tab3 4.4.2). The strange thing is I am getting an error that I do not see when running on my new devices (Android 6+).
When I hit the debug button, a Gradle build is shot off and I get the following error:

```
06/21 15:55:35: Launching splashActivity
The APK file C:\Users\me\Documents\src\myapp\build\outputs\apk\MyApp\debug\10-MyApp.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

The file is not there, but is not there when I run against the newer versions, which successfully debug. Is Android Studio doing something different due to the older version? Do I need to make some sort of Gradle adjustment?

My Gradle build appends a version to the front of the APK, could that be the problem? Here is the Gradle file (I have removed the flavors, have a ton of them):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.1.10"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        flavor.ext.set('directoryPath', '')
        flavor.ext.set('apkName', '')
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        MyApp {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'myapp'
        }
        Flavor1 {
            applicationId 'com.flavor1.flavor'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'flavor1'
        }
     }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def apkName = variant.productFlavors[0].apkName
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            if (apkName != '')
                flavor = apkName;
            //add here your logic to customize the name of the apk
            outputFileName = "${variant.versionCode}-${flavor}.apk"
        }
        variant.assemble.doLast { assemble ->
            //copy the apk in another directory, add here your
            //logic to customize the destination folder
            copy {
                from variant.outputs*.outputFile
                into "C:/AndroidBuilds/MyApp.Build/${variant.productFlavors[0].directoryPath}"
            }
            //if you don't want to delete the file after copying it comment the line below
            delete variant.outputs*.outputFile
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed dependencies and such to make it smaller, and changed names to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, it was the following line of code in Gradle, that was deleting the variant. Apparently it is needed to run on older versions of Android:

```
            //if you don't want to delete the file after copying it comment the line below
//            delete variant.outputs*.outputFile
```